# How to insert new data of Geo-location into SQLite database every 30 seconds in android?

Tags: android

```
    GeoInformation geoInformation = new GeoInformation(d,cellid,locationid,lon,lat,m,mn,address,Signalstrength,ipAddress,ttt,timestamp,carrier);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String jsonData = gson.toJson(geoInformation);
    Log.i("**",jsonData);
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, jsonData, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, jsonData, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    geolocationtDbHelper = new GeolocationDbHelper(context);
    sqLiteDatabase = geolocationtDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    geolocationtDbHelper.addInformation(timeData, jsonData, sqLiteDatabase);
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Data Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    geolocationtDbHelper.close();
```

Comment: Correct your Question formating.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Isha, we haw many solutions for repeating any task every 30 seconds in android:
So you can do it with the android handler with post delay, which will call after 30 secs.

```
new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //code here which you need to repeat after 30 secs.
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Call after 30 secs", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                new Handler().postDelayed(this, 1000 * 30);
            }
        });
```

I hope It will help you.
If you wants to read about the Handler you can follow this link :
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable, long)